# GUID for globally unique identifier in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

How to create GUID in php

1-guid stands for globally unique identifier generally used to create random unique strings in php, create access token in php

2-Mostly use of GUID for generating access token, generate unique id, generating unique string in php. Using this article how to create guide in php you can create a random string for any use to keep unique

3-GUID consists of alphanumeric characters only and is grouped in five groups separated by hyphens as seen in this example:

3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301

Eg:-

```
<?php
/**
* Generate Globally Unique Identifier (GUID)
* E.g. 2EF40F5A-ADE8-5AE3-2491-85CA5CBD6EA7
*
* @param boolean $include_braces Set to true if the final guid needs
*        to be wrapped in curly braces
* @return string

*/
function generateGuid($include_braces = false) {
if (function_exists('com_create_guid')) {
if ($include_braces === true) {
return com_create_guid();
} else {
return substr(com_create_guid(), 1, 36);
}
} else {
mt_srand((double) microtime() * 10000);
$charid = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
$guid = substr($charid,  0, 8) . '-' .
substr($charid,  8, 4) . '-' .
substr($charid, 12, 4) . '-' .
substr($charid, 16, 4) . '-' .
substr($charid, 20, 12);
if ($include_braces) {
$guid = '{' . $guid . '}';
}
return $guid;
}
}
?>
```

---

Output: 
$GUID = getGUID();
echo $GUID;

Comment: GUID is globally unique indentifier

Comment: Use Google next time... http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php

Comment: Maybe learn how to use google and then create a GUID